# Form validation with a large set of input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

There is a group of input boxes, for example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control my-input" name="q1" size="63" value="<?= set_value("q1"); ?>">
<input type="text" class="form-control my-input" name="q2" size="63" value="<?= set_value("q2"); ?>">
....
<input type="text" class="form-control my-input" name="q100" size="63" value="<?= set_value("q30"); ?>">
```

There are 30 input boxes, from q1 to q30

If I would like to validate them, I need to set

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('q1', lang("q1"), 'required');
```

30 times, and the validation error message will show 30 times if nothing important.

Therefore, I would like to:

1. Assume the q15 is not require, loop through the post array and check whether other input box are input or empty.
2. Only show one error message if any one of the required input box is not input

How to achieve this in codeigniter?

Comment: Use any loop and iterate to 30

Comment: thanks a lot. how to handle for the case where the name is not following a pattern, and how to show only one error message if any one of input box fail validated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code sample

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++){
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('q' + $i, lang('q' + $i), 'required');
}
```

**UPDATE**
When names don't follow pattern:

```
$names = [1=>'q1', 'a1', 'd3', ...];

for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++){
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($names[$i], lang($names[$i]), 'required');
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , how can I only show one error message if any one of the required input box is not input?

Comment: create an array for names and use this array to set names; see update;

Comment: the required error will show multiple times, is there any advice to show only one custom error message . eg. "Please fill in all the fields" . Thanks for your reply

Comment: can I simply ignore the key / just loop the post input array and get the given key from the array

Comment: You want to set validation rules based on fields submitted right?

Comment: would like to validate all post data with excluding serveral input box, and if fail validate only show one error message. Is it better skip the usage of codeigniter form validation and write the own one? Thanks